# PHP get specific data from xml file

Tags: php, xml

This is XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<UW xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd">
  <UWdata>
    <List>
      <IdProduct>1</IdProduct>
      <ProductName>product</ProductName>
      <ProductNameDE>product</ProductNameDE>
      <ProductNameEN>product</ProductNameEN>
      <Uf>1</Uf>
      <PSIg>1</PSIg>
      <Ug>1</Ug>
    </List>
  </UWdata>
</UW> 


$lines_array=file($url);
$lines_string=implode('',$lines_array);
$xml=simplexml_load_string($lines_string) or die("Error: Cannot create object");
```

I try with this

```
echo $xml->UWdata[1]->ProductName;
```

But it doesn't return anything.I want to return Product name.

Comment: any result from `print_r($xml);` ? and try ` simplexml_load_file` insread of `simplexml_load_string`

Comment: Your index should be `[0]` and you missed out the `->List` from the object. Also you need to cast to string: `echo (string)$xml->UWdata[0]->List->ProductName`

Comment: I got  Error: Cannot create object when try to use simplexml_load_file and then echo $xml->UWdata[1]->ProductName;

Comment: Alseo when I try echo $xml->UW[0]-> UWdata[0]->ProductName;
 it return nothing.

Comment: @BiljanaGlumac did you try what I suggested?

Comment: @Nick I try and return nothing

Answer (score 1):

Sample code, Use `simplexml_load_string`

```
<?php
$a = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<UW xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd">
  <UWdata>
    <List>
      <IdProduct>1</IdProduct>
      <ProductName>product</ProductName>
      <ProductNameDE>product</ProductNameDE>
      <ProductNameEN>product</ProductNameEN>
      <Uf>1</Uf>
      <PSIg>1</PSIg>
      <Ug>1</Ug>
    </List>
  </UWdata>
</UW>';

$xml=simplexml_load_string($a) or die("Error: Cannot create object");

echo ($xml->UWdata->List->ProductName);
?>
```

Comment: When I past your code and run it does return data, but when I call file_get_contents with my url and do it on my returned xml from url it return nothing.

Answer (score 0):

When you load the xml file using the php `simplexml_load_file` function to a variable. The veritable becomes an object.

```
<?php 
$xml=simplexml_load_file("/path/to/the/file.xml");
?>
```

So, in your case, the `$xml` variable becomes a multi-level object where every elements of xml file are key of the object. Like: **UWdata**.
So, as `$xml` is a multi-level object, to access the element under **UWdata**, under **List** under **ProductName**, you have to code like bellow.

```
echo $xml->UWdata->List->ProductName."<br>";
```

Here,
`UWdata` is the key of `$xml` object.

`List` is the key of `UWdata`.

`ProductName` is the key of `List`.

Finally, you will get the value of key element `ProductName` = **product**

Answer (score -1):

I modified your script and put the xml in an external file called `testxml.xml`, as it should be. Always separate the function and the data it's supposed to handle. I used your xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<UW xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd">
  <UWdata>
    <List>
      <IdProduct>1</IdProduct>
      <ProductName>productTEST</ProductName>
      <ProductNameDE>product</ProductNameDE>
      <ProductNameEN>product</ProductNameEN>
      <Uf>1</Uf>
      <PSIg>1</PSIg>
      <Ug>1</Ug>
    </List>
  </UWdata>
</UW>
```

And with the following script it returns `productTEST` only.

```
$xmlstr = file_get_contents('./testxml.xml');
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlstr);
$json = json_encode($xml);
$array = json_decode($json,TRUE);
echo $array['UWdata']['List']['ProductName'];
```

Hope this helps.

//edit:
While I do not know your project, you might want to take a foreach-approach if it is possible for your xml to contain more than one `List` element

Comment: It doesn't help on my console it return nothing is there maybe a problem in calling of php file. I call like this.   $.ajax({
        url: "/wp-admin/uw_calulation.php",
        type: 'GET',
       success:function(data)
{
console.log(data);
}  
      

    });